# What's the correct aurelia router config for routes #/items/ AND #/items/:id/summary?

Tags: aurelia, router

I'm trying to get a parent/child router working for this basic hierarchy:

```
#/items             (show options to select a specific item)
#/items/:id/summary (specific item summary)
#/items/:id/detail  (specific item detail)
```

[image: Target UI]

**Detail**

I have the following routes defined in the parent router:

```
[{
  route: '', redirect: 'items'
}, {
  route: ['items'],
  name: 'Items',
  viewPorts: {
    itemNavigation: {moduleId: '....'},
    currentItem: { moduleId: '......' }
  },
  nav: true,
  title: 'Items'
},
{
  route: ['items/:id'],
  viewPorts: {
    itemNavigation: {moduleId: '......'},
    currentItem: { moduleId: '......' }
  },
  nav: false
}...
```

I have the following routes defined in the 'currentItem' module child router:

```
[{
    route: '',
    moduleId: '....',
    name: 'noRouteSelected',
    nav: false
  },  {
    route: 'summary',
    moduleId: '....',
    name: 'summary',
    nav: true,
    title: 'Summary'
  }, {
    route: 'detail',
    moduleId: '....',
    name: 'detail',
    nav: true,
    title: 'Detail'
  }...
```

This looks ok but if I navigate to a child route (e.g. '#/items/123/summary'), because nav is false, there's nothing shown as 'active' in the main nav menu (the red circle in the image). That's fair enough but if I merge the 2 parent configs along the lines of:

`route: ['items', 'items/:id']`

I get a shed load of exceptions being thrown:

`Error: A value is required for route parameter 'id' in route 'investments'.`

If I user the optional config:

`route: ['items/:id?']`

then I need to specify the href parameter in the config, but I've no idea what that should be in this scenario. Should I instead be using a Navigation Strategy? (examples would be great!)

Can anyone help? The documentation is somewhat lacking on this front.

Comment: Couldn't you use `all` as the value for `id` in the href parameter? Then you just check if the value of the id parameter to see if it is `all`.

Comment: @AshleyGrant - a good workaround suggest. Many thanks. I am still holding out hope that I'm missing some trick, as this doesn't seem right having a 'magic' id (and isn't intuitive). I'd have to put a redirect in from '#/items/' -> '#/items/all

Comment: I'm personally not a huge fan of using child routers. I try to avoid them if at all possible. So you might consider how to solve this without a child router.

Comment: @JohnStephenson What is the actual problem you're trying to solve though? You just want a menu item to appear as active, why don't you create a visible menu item for it then? What's the logic of making `summary` appear as active even though it's not, and then actually navigating to a specific item's summary nothing would visually change (which sounds confusing). Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @FredKleuver I've added an image to hopefully explain. The red circle indicates what I want but I'm not getting ATM.

Comment: But in the image you have an item selected, so what needs to be visible when you click `items` but not selected any particular item?

Comment: There's a 'Nothing selected' option in the dropdown in the itemNavigation viewport, and the 'currentItem' viewport shows the 'noRouteSelected' module.

Comment: And then would you be able to click Summary or Detail, or are those tabs hidden/disabled?

Comment: The later - if their is no :id param in the active for the currentItem I don't show anything (well - only a 'please select an item message').

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would structure your app:

In the top-level page:

```
{
    route: '',
    redirect: 'items'
},
{
    route: 'items',
    name: 'items',
    moduleId: './items',
    title: 'Items',
    nav: true
}
```

In the Items page:

```
{
    route: '',
    name: 'no-item-selected',
    moduleId: './some-empty-view',
    nav: false
},
{
    route: ':id',
    name: 'item',
    moduleId: './item',
    nav: false
}
```

In the Item page:

```
{
    route: '',
    redirect: 'summary'
},
{
    route: 'summary',
    moduleId: './item-summary',
    name: 'item-summary',
    title: 'Summary',
    nav: true
},
{
    route: 'detail',
    moduleId: './item-detail',
    name: 'item-detail',
    title: 'Detail',
    nav: true
}
```

In the Item view model itself you could store the `Router` you get during `configureRouter`, and then during `activate()` set the title accordingly if you want to, since "Items | Item | Detail" is probably a bit silly (so I left the title out for the Item page)

You could also completely omit the nested child router in `item` page and just have both `summary` and `detail` in there, showing/hiding them according to some other logic. Though it can be neat to have the back/forward navigation capabilities and be able to directly link to something.

**Original answer** (this was addressing what turned out to be a typo, but i'll just leave it for context)

Change your route from `items:id` to `items/:id`. Basically every "segment" of a route (be it static, optional, dynamic) needs to be separated by a slash or route-recognizer doesn't map them correctly.

You don't need to make the route optional with a setup like this. You won't be selecting an item without an id anyway (and if you create a new one, you'd typically just pass `new` or something similar as the id so your view can distinguish)

Comment: apologies, that was a typo. I've updated the question with the '/'s.

Comment: If I don't make it optional I get the problems mentioned in the OP. Possible reason for making the route optional is the need for #/items/ show options to select a specific item, which seems reasonable in my head :-). I'm using one viewport for the 'item navigation', and one for the 'current item' (if provided) in the parent route config.

Comment: The problem is that if you make the route parameter `/:id` optional, then route-recognizer has no way to distinguish between the `items` and `items/:id?` route. If you are navigating to `items` then it may be either route. I actually agree with Ashley's suggestion here; using a "magic id" is the only "trick" to make this work. I've worked a lot with the router, wrote a fairly extensive plugin for it etc, and I know quite well what it can or cannot do. Of course there are multiple ways (some not involving the router) to solve your problem, but with a child router, you'll need a magic id :)

Comment: Thanks for your continuing input! I understand that optional problem, but I'd expect that if I had "route: ['items', 'items/:id']" (not optional), which is logically equivalent to the optional configuration, I'm explicitly saying 'hey don't worry about it, proceed to load the modules, I'll handle the parameters'. Perhaps it's not as simple as that in practise though :-(.

Comment: It can be that simple if you really don't need the parameters to come in during `activate()`. The reason it needs you to specify a `href` is because no assumptions can be made about what you actually want to navigate to if you navigate to `/items/:id?`. So you'd just set `href` to `/items` and it will stop nagging about that. Be aware though that now the `:id` parameter will be passed to your parent viewModel's activate rather than to the child viewModel that probably needs it.

Comment: 'all' magic Id is looking better and better :-). Thanks for your suggestion though. The aurelia router has a lot of functionality in it but it never seems to do exactly what I want. Hey ho...

Comment: I think you might be slightly overthinking this though. See my updated answer, does that make more sense perhaps?